# Retrofit is unable to create call adapter

Tags: android, retrofit

Esta es mi UserService interface:

```
@GET("/login/{usu}/{pass}")
        Call login (@Path("usu") String username, @Path("pass") String password);
```

La llamada que hago es la siguiente:

```
public static Retrofit getClient(String url){
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Necesito hacer un login pero tengo este error.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se genera porque no puede parsear los datos que recibe.

Crea una clase `LoginResponse` que contenga los datos para que sepa como tiene que parsearlo.

```
@GET("/login/{usu}/{pass}")
Call<LoginResponse> login (@Path("usu") String username, @Path("pass") String password);
```

Comment: hice algunos cambios y mi URL es esta "http://misitio.cl/pdo3/valida.php?jq=consultarUsuario&usuario=+usu+&password=+pass"
¿Sigue estando bien la forma en que la consulto?

Comment: no, si cambias la url tenes que cambiar la anotacion y los parametros

Comment: quedaría como  
@GET("valida.php/consultarUsuario/{usu}&{pass}")
Call <ResObj> login (@Path( value= "usu", encoded = true) String username, @Path( value= "pass", encoded = true) String password);